# Expand div with no content to bottom of window

Tags: html, css, height

I've read a lot of the answers to similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none address my seemingly unique case.

I have a div below my footer which has no content, just a left and right border for ornamental purposes.

[image]

I want to show a little bit of those border lines by default, which works in normal browsing by giving them a height of 20px or something, but dragging the browser window down reveals where they end. So I tried giving them a height of 100%. Referencing a variety of answers on Stack Overflow and other sites, I tried

```
    html, body {height; 100%;}
    borderlines {height: 100%;}/*also tried with min-height: 100%*/
```

But this just made my div extend hugely past the bottom of the screen and give me a scrollbar.

**How can I show 20px worth of these lines when the user scrolls to the bottom of my page, but also get the div to continue to the bottom of the window in case the window gets expanded?**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5keqf68x/

Comment: what is the html code you use for those borderlines?

Comment: `.botlines{
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    border-left: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
    border-right: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
}`

I tried adding overflow-y: hidden and position: relative on reading some other suggestions, but no luck...

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle with html+css showing what's your goal? I've read twice your post but I actually don't understand what you want to do..

Comment: As much as your image is helpful, Im afraid the programmer who can see through computer screens went out to lunch :) Without some code, its hard to solve a code issue, preferably a jsFiddle.net working example

Comment: Here's a JS fiddle, you cans see what's happening here. http://jsfiddle.net/5keqf68x/

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle output window, bottom div looks fine but the div on top seems to reveal where the lines ends. Adding `margin : 0px;` in `html, body` fixes that.

http://jsfiddle.net/5keqf68x/3/

Comment: That is a quirk of jsfiddle. The problem is the bottom div. In yours the bottom is set to 20 pixels, but if you were able to resize the window that wouldn't work. See how in my original the bottom lines extend so far down?